# Convert .mat files to signal .slx file

Tags: matlab, encoding, signals, simulink, data-conversion

I'm trying to insert .mat files into a simulink model.
The model requires signal format data as an input.
I haven't found any .mat to .slx converter as a block, and my matlab coding knowledge is really amateur.

Would really appreciate any help.
Thank you in advance

Comment: How are you trying to insert them? Because if its an input, you can always run a .m file and then use "from workspace" block

Comment: You can't convert a .mat file to a .xls file.  One is a MATLAB data file; one is a Simulink model file.  What you can do is `load` the data from the .mat file into MATLAB, then as @AnderBiguri has indictated, us the `From Workspace` block to load the data into Simulink.  Alternatively, if the data in the .mat file is of the required format, then you can use the `From File` block to load the data directly into the model.

Answer (score 0):

as suggested above load .mat file in matlab workspace. once you load you will find relevant signals in matlab basework space. than right click on the signal line to with you want to attach a particular signal and then select  properties and a signal properties window will open up then add the signal name from base workspace in the window and check the box signal name must resolve to Simulink signal object